# Showing URL in a webpage

Tags: php, mysql, database, url

I need a URL based on a table in Database, like this:

```
<a href='edit.php?id=[]>e</a>
```

Here the id should be the final id of the table. That means, if I have a total 45 id in the database table, the URL should be like this:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=45">e</a>
```

I tried this code below but didn't succeed. Please help me.

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$query1 = "SELECT id FROM addd ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo <a href='edit.php?id="$data[0]"'>e</a>;

?>
```

Comment: You need a GET array

Comment: and this will throw you a parse error `echo <a href='edit.php?id="$data[0]"'>e</a>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<a href='edit.php?id={$data[0]}'>e</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much....it is perfectly done....

Answer (score 1):

You can also Do it using the query.

```
  SELECT max(id) FROM addd;
```

and the prob is with

```
  echo <a href='edit.php?id="$data[0]"'>e</a>;
```

you got to do it like:

```
  echo "<a href='edit.php?id={$data[0]}'>click</a>";
```

Hope that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$data[0].'">e</a>';
```